# Automate AWS Marketplace publishing through CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-marketplace

I have my product uploaded to AWS as an AMI through Hashicorp's Packer. Now I'ld like to automate the last step, publishing it to the marketplace. The product already exists, it's only about adding a revision.

After reading [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/awsmarketplace/using-aws-cli-to-build-and-manage-your-organizations-private-marketplace-via-apis/), the [API_StartChangeSet doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/API_StartChangeSet.html#API_StartChangeSet_Examples), this [add revisions user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/data-exchange/latest/userguide/add-revisions.html) & fiddling with the marketplace console, I think I just have to

```
aws marketplace-catalog start-change-set --catalog AWSMarketplace --change-set-name "$VERSION" --change-set '[ {"ChangeType": "AddRevisions", "Entity": {"Identifier": "REDACTED@29","Type": "ServerProduct@1.0"}, "Details": "{\"DataSetArn\": \"?????\", \"RevisionArns\": [\"?????\"] }" ]'
```

I'm having a hard time coming up with "Details" part. I've my AMI id. I guess that goes in the RevisionsArns ? What should I put in the DataSetArn, the "EntityArn" from the output of `aws marketplace-catalog describe-entity --catalog AWSMarketplace --entity-id REDACTED` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't found the good documentation, my last link being about AWS Data Exchange, whose "Details" field's contents were confusing.

Here the relevant documentation: [Marketplace catalog AMI add version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/ami-products.html#ami-add-version), and here's the snippet I was looking for

```json
      "Details": "{
        \"Version\": {
          \"VersionTitle\": \"*My new title*\",
          \"ReleaseNotes\": \"*My new Release notes*\"
        },
        \"DeliveryOptions\": [
          {
            \"Details\": {
              \"AmiDeliveryOptionDetails\": {
                \"AmiSource\": {
                  \"AmiId\": \"ami-1234567890abcdef\",
                  \"AccessRoleArn\": \"arn:aws:iam::12345678901:role/AwsMarketplaceAmiIngestion\",
                  \"UserName\": \"ec2-user\",
                  \"OperatingSystemName\": \"AMAZONLINUX\",
                  \"OperatingSystemVersion\": \"Amazon Linux 2 AMI 2.0.20210126.0 x86_64 HVM gp2\"
                },
                \"UsageInstructions\": \"Easy to use AMI\",
                \"RecommendedInstanceType\": \"m4.xlarge\",
                \"SecurityGroups\": [
                  {
                    \"IpProtocol\": \"tcp\",
                    \"FromPort\": 443,
                    \"ToPort\": 443,
                    \"IpRanges\": [
                      \"0.0.0.0/0\"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Details` facet here is just a product type specific facet, encoded as json string. For the AMI that you are offering in the AWS Marketplace, it could include support information, region availability or any other info that provides a descriptive text regarding your change. For example:

```
  "Details": "{\"Description\":{}, \"PromotionalResources\":{}, \"RegionAvailability\":{}, \"SupportInformation\":{}}",
```

The example you found does not necessarily mean that you have to have `EntityArn` and `RevisionsArns`. The `Details` facet is used as an information describing the details of your change.

Check [here](http://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/welcome.html#working-with-details).